# How to implement the Swiping-Gesture for a PageView using a GestureRecognizer in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-pageview

I am trying to recreate the MediaPicker from Instagram.

The current structure of this screen looks like this:

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar(context),
      body: PageView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //disable the "normal" pageview scrolling
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            pageIndex = index;
          });
        },
        controller: pageController,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: buildPreviewWidget(selection, _buildCropPreview), //this cropview has a gesture recognizer on it
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 2),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onHorizontalDragStart: (details) {
                      double offset = screenWidth - details.localPosition.dx;
                      pageController.jumpTo(offset);
                    },
                    onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
                      double offset = screenWidth - details.localPosition.dx;
                      pageController.jumpTo(offset);
                    },
                    child:MediaGrid( //this is the media grid
                            allowMultiSelection: multiSelectable,
                            collection: allCollection),
                  )),
            ],
          ),
          CameraScreen(),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: buildBottomNavigationBar(),
    );
```

The initial problem was, that whenever I dragged around in the cropview, the swiping gesture of the pageview got triggered which was not what I wanted.

So my idea was to disable the standard way of scrolling with `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` and then wrap only the `MediaGrid()` with a `GestureRecognizer()` so that I can achieve the same swipe animation with the help of the PageViews `pageController.jumpTo()` but only on the `MediaGrid()`

However my implementation seems to be bad because the pageview is stuttering like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guh9k.jpg

How do I smooth the stuttering or is there an even better way to achieve this?

Comment: in `onHorizontalDragUpdate` case try `pageController.jumpTo(pageController.offset - details.delta.dx)` - the stuttering could be related to changed "local position"

Comment: Sorry, I didn`t have had the chance to test it yet, will let you know asap.

Comment: @pskink seems like this improved the stuttering by a lot but the pageview still wants to snap to one of the screens. So when I drag it to 50% offset it moves on its own. 

I have the feeling this is because I call `pageController.jumpTo()` only in the `onHorizontalDragUpdate` so when I stop and only hold the screen at 50%, the event doesn`t get fired any more. Is there a way to animate as long as I touch the screen?

Comment: most likely you need `onHorizontalDragEnd`

Comment: I finally found a solution. Turns out the PageView has a `pageSnapping` property which defaults to true. 

I am now setting `pageSnapping` to false when `onHorizontalDragStart` and to true when `onHorizontalDragEnd` works like a charm. Thanks!